# Omnifaces: Socket; have multiple events / different remoteCommand scripts?

Tags: jsf, websocket, omnifaces

I´m using o:socket for my chat application.
Currently I can send and receive messages, but now I would like to have different events.
Event1: sendMessage (send a message to channel)
Event2: a user is typing.

Currently my page is like that:

```
<h:form>
    <o:socket channel="chatChannel"
        user="#{loginChatController.chatUser.id}" scope="view"
        onmessage="chatScript">
    </o:socket>

    <p:remoteCommand name="chatScript" immediate="true" update=":chatForm"
        global="false" />
</h:form>
```

Here my WebSocket:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ChatWebsocket implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7615791377170410627L;

        @Inject
        @Push(channel = "chatChannel")
        private PushContext push;

        /**
         * Push Chat
         * 
         * @param recipientUser
         */
        public void pushUser(@Observes ChatPushEvent event) {

            if (event.getChatUserList() == null)
                return;

            push.send("chatForm", event.getChatUserList());

        }
}
```

And here my ChatPushEvent class:

```
public class ChatPushEvent {

    private String message;
    private ChatUser chatUser;
    private List<Long> chatUserList;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public ChatPushEvent(String message, ChatUser chatUser) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.chatUser = chatUser;
    }

    public ChatPushEvent(String message, List<Long> chatUserList) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.chatUserList = chatUserList;
    }

    public List<Long> getChatUserList() {
        return chatUserList;
    }

    public void setChatUserList(List<Long> chatUserList) {
        this.chatUserList = chatUserList;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ChatUser getChatUser() {
        return chatUser;
    }

    public void setChatUser(ChatUser chatUser) {
        this.chatUser = chatUser;
    }
}
```

The idea is now to add at the ChatPushEvent class another String like "eventType". This can be "NORMAL_MESSAGE" or "TYPING"...

In my JSF page I need now this to call p:remoteCommand1 or p:remoteCommand2:
How can I do this / get the ChatPushEvent in the JSF page?

So I need something like this

```
    <h:form>
        <o:socket channel="chatChannel"
            user="#{loginChatController.chatUser.id}" scope="view"
            onmessage="chatScript">
        </o:socket>

        <p:remoteCommand name="chatScript" immediate="true" update=":chatForm"
            global="false" />

<p:remoteCommand name="chatScriptTyping" actionListener="doSomething" immediate="true" update=":chatForm"
            global="false" />
    </h:form>
```

How can I call **chatScriptTyping** or **chatScript**

Comment: Already checked section titled [UI update design hints](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket#ui) in socket doc?

Comment: Thank you will try it... is it also allowed to have: push.send("someEvent", event.getChatUserList());